# Has the UK ever used the Diplomatic and Consular Premises Act 1987 to enter an embassy without approval?

Tags: united-kingdom, diplomacy

The [Diplomatic and Consular Premises Act 1987](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_and_Consular_Premises_Act_1987) allows the UK to remove the diplomatic status of any place.

Has the UK already used this act to enter an embassy/consulate/etc?
They recently [threatened to do so](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-19259623).

*Related but more general question: [Has any foreign embassy ever been entered without permission?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/2863)*

Comment: -1 because the answer is contained in the linked document...

Comment: @Lohoris. Nothing wrong with a [self-answered question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) per se.

Comment: cant remove my comment because smartphone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes once. Cambodian embassy was de-recognised in 1988 as it was vacant and squatters had moved in.

[Diplomatic and Consular Premises Act 1987](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_and_Consular_Premises_Act_1987) (how did you link this and not...?)